# Are all recurrence relations solvable by generating functions? A tricky one

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have found this recurrence relation:

$$r_0 = 0; \\ r_w = 1; \\r_{n+1} = 2r_n - r_{n-1};\; \text{for}\; 0 < n < w$$

(from section 20.1 here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_notes.pdf)

The coefficient for the general $n$ term is solved by using linear recurrence relations. I have tried to solve it by generating function but I can't. It seems that the problem is that we don't have *actual* initial conditions but only a condition for 0 that does not add anything and then a jump until $w$. And we need a value for $r_1$ that you can't solve until you solve the entire recurrence relation.

**My try:** searching $G(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}r_{n}x^{n}$, multiplying the recurrence by $x^{n+1}$ and summing from $n=1$:

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}r_{n+1}x^{n+1} = 2\sum_{n\geq 1}r_{n}x^{n+1} - \sum_{n\geq 1}r_{n-1}x^{n+1} $$

$$G(x) - r_1 = 2xG(x) - x^2(G(x) - r_0)$$

But how can you advance from here if you don't know $r_1$? Are all the recurrence relations solvable by generating functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing conveniently the sum limits we have

$$
\frac 1x\left(G(x)-r_0\right)-2G(x) + x\left(G(x)-r_w x^w\right) = 0
$$

or

$$
G(x) = \frac{r_w x^{w+2}+r_0}{1-2x+x^2}
$$

NOTE

$$
\sum_{k=0}^w\left(\frac 1x r_{k+1} x^{k+1}-2r_k x^k+x r_{k-1}x^{k-1}\right)=0
$$

NOTE

Considering $w = 5, r_0 = 0, r_5= 1$ we have

$$
\frac{x^7}{1-2x+x^2} = x^5+2x^4+3x^3+4x^2+5x+\cdots
$$

so we have

$$
r_4 = 2, r_3 = 3, r_2 = 4, r_1 = 5
$$

and as we can easily verify, they obey the recurrence

$$
r_{k+1}-2r_k+r_{k-1} = 0
$$

Comment: Can you be more explicit of such limits? I guess you are multiplying the recurrence relation by $x^n$, but what are those limits?

Comment: @David Please. See note attached.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. The key is the manipulation of the lower but also upper limits of the sums. But why did you choose the sum from 0 to $w$? It's okay that the recurrence relation ends at $w$, but it does not begin at 0 (it begins at 1)... Are the limits of the summation between 0 and $w$ the only possible choice?

Comment: @David The sum between $0 \le k \le w$ is needed to cope with $r_0$ and $r_w$ as recurrence elements.

Comment: Thx. In your example with $w=5$, after you divide the polynomials, you get the quotient of the division plus a term $\frac{7x-6}{x^2 -2x +1} = \frac{7}{x-1} + \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ and when you expand this term as a power series you also get coefficients of powers like $x^5$ or $x^4$. Wouldn't that spoil the recurrence?

Comment: @David This expansion is possible only for $|x| < 1$ and even there the recurrence is observed.

Comment: Ok, so we have 2 "regimes", so to say, the $x^5+2x^4+3x^3+4x^2+5x$ has validity for all x and the expansion of the remainder/divisor that is valid for abs(x) < 1. We can work in whatever of them but not mix them, right? In the end, the gen function is $x^5 + 2x^4 +3x^3 +4x^2 +5x +0$. Am I right?

Comment: @David The expansion including $\frac{7x-6}{x^2-2x+1}$ generates terms $r_k x^k$ for $k \ge 7$. We have only one regimen because the recurrence we need is as the question demands, for $0\lt n\lt w$

Answer (score 1):

In this case we can see that the general solution for arbitrary $r_0$ and $r_1$ is

$r_n = nr_1-(n-1)r_0$

Togather with $r_0=0$ and $r_w=1$ this gives us $r_1=\frac{1}{w}$ and $r_n=\frac{n}{w}$.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution is not based on generating functions

Comment: You can use generating functions to derive $r_n = nr_1-(n-1)r_0$. Point is that you don't need to be given values for $r_0$ and $r_1$ to proceed - any two values in the sequence will do.

Comment: @David Solving the generating function equation for arbitrary $r_0$ and $r_1$ gives you $G(x) = \frac{r_0}{1-x}+\frac{r_1-r_0}{(1-x)^2}$ from which you get $r_n=r_0+n(r_1-r_0)=nr_1-(n-1)r_0$.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible that you could detail more how did you find the $G(x)$ in terms of $r_0$ and $r_1$. I can't get that expression. Your comments on that any two values are valid seem quite interesting but I need more details.